# MySQL - Select Query

Tags: mysql

I am some hours trying to make a query, but I haven't sucess! :(

With this query I select `users_id` and `purchase_date` of users that bought by key:

```
SELECT user_id, purchase_date FROM purchases AS p
INNER JOIN keys AS pc
ON p.transaction_id = pc.unique_id
WHERE pc.generator_id = 96768
GROUP BY user_id
```

Now I want select from these users who bought after this.
Eg.: `SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE user_id = {users of query above} AND purchase_date > {purchase_date of query above}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join a table with a subquery:

```
SELECT pr.*
 FROM purchases pr
 INNER JOIN ( 
   SELECT p.user_id, p.purchase_date
   FROM purchases p
   INNER JOIN keys pc ON p.transaction_id = pc.unique_id
   WHERE pc.generator_id = 96768
   GROUP BY p.user_id
 ) p0 ON pr.user_id = p0.user_id AND pr.purchase_date > p0.purchase_date
```

Info: [MySQL JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)